# Dropdown menu should not be closed if it is clicked inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I put a panel inside a bootstrap dropdown, but when I click inside the panel, the dropdown goes away. I got many solution on stackoverflow but it didn't work for me. How can i prevent panel from disappearing when i click inside.`enter code here`

```
   <span class="input-group-addon dropdown">
      <label class="dropdown-toggle " id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown aria-expanded="false">Advanced Search  <span class="caret"></span></label>
      <div class="panel panel-default panel-body dropdown-menu " role="menu"" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" style="width:860px; margin-left:-700px">
        Panel content
      </div>
   </span>
```

Comment: can you please post a jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like this:if you click on the body it checks the parent class,if you click on the dropdown if parent has class `.dropdown-parentclass` then the dropdown does not close.

```
$('body').click(function(event){
    if ($(event.target).parent('.dropdown-parentclass').size()>0) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: above solution didn't work for me. Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

try using the code below. It will close the dropdown only when you click out side the container.

```
      $(document).on("mouseup", function (e) {
        var container = $(".panel");

        if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container
            && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // nor a descendant of the container
        {
            container.hide();
        }
        else {

        }
    });
```

Comment: above solution didn't work for me. Let me know if you need more information.